# Gulp + Sass + Combine Media Queries + Sourcemaps + Minify

Tags: sass, media-queries, gulp, source-maps

I'm trying to get the above combination working but am unable to. I have tried the following combinations:

1)

```
var sass = require('gulp-ruby-sass');

gulp.task('sass',function () {
    gulp.src('_scss/main.scss')
        .pipe(sass({
            loadPath: ['_scss'],
            style: "compressed",
            trace: true,
            sourcemap: true,
            sourcemapPath: "../../../_scss",
            noCache: true,
            require: ['sass-media_query_combiner']
    }))
```

2)

```
var sass = require('gulp-ruby-sass');
var cmq = require('gulp-combine-media-queries');
var cssmin = require('gulp-cssmin');

gulp.task('sass',function () {
    gulp.src('_scss/main.scss')
        .pipe(sass({
            loadPath: ['_scss'],
            style: "nested",
            trace: true,
            sourcemap: true,
            sourcemapPath: "../../../_scss",
            noCache: true
    }))
    .pipe(cmq())
    .pipe(cssmin())
```

3) I also tried using gulp-sass + gulp-combine-media-queries + gulp-minify-css + gulp-sourcemaps

Before moving to Gulp, I was using this build command in ST2:

```
"cmd": ["sass", "--update", "${project_path}/web/_scss/main.scss:${project_path}/web/resources/css/main.css", "--stop-on-error", "--no-cache", "--style", "compressed","-r","sass-media_query_combiner"],
```

link to question on [reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/webdev/comments/2d89hn/some_help_with_gulp_needed/), also [sass-media_query_combiner](https://github.com/aaronjensen/sass-media_query_combiner/issues/11) and [gulp-ruby-sass](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-ruby-sass/issues/107)

Comment: Did you have any luck with this in the end?

Comment: Sadly no. I have added links to other places that I have posted this.

Answer (score 1):

".pipe(cmq())" should be before ".pipe(gulp.dest())"

```
gulp.task('sass', function() {
return gulp.src("./*.scss")
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(cmq())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(".css/"))
    .pipe(reload({stream: true}))
```

});